# Select all cells that are not empty MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I have a table where I need to find wheter the cell is empty or not. 
I don't have the specific column name so I need to display all of the cells that are not empty. (PHP solution would fit too.) Thank you!

Here is my piece of code:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `FACILITIES` WHERE `room_id` = '{$row['id']}'");
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
            if(empty($row[''])) { //What should I fill in in the $row variable?
                  alert("Empty");
            }
}
```

I have tried doing in in PHP, but a MYSQL solution would fit too.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

a simple sql that you can rewrite and use would be similar...

[**<kbd>sqlfiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/230a87/1)

```
select * from t where 
(col1 is null or col1='')
or
(col2 is null or col2='')
;
```

[**<kbd>sqlfiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/230a87/1)

Comment: Empty and null are not the same thing.

Comment: Of course not Mihai, but I wanted to give a push in some direction. The question is not so detailed , and the quality of a question result in those answers.

Comment: That's even not what I asked, I know how to do it by this way, but I thought there is some more effective way.

Answer (score 0):

You should prevent that problem in the first place. Handle that on DB design level. If you want all your records having values in every column,  then define the columns so: `not null`.